# How can i install jbpm form(plugin) for eclipse?? [JBPM 5.2]

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jbpm, bpmn

Kris shows a [demo](http://planet.jboss.org/post/reward_system_demo) in jbpm where eclipse has a option to create jBPM2 forms.

I have installed jbpm plugin for eclipse and its working fine,but i am not seeing jbpm form in my eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form generation is part of the latest features we're adding for jBPM 5.3.  You can download the latest jBPM & Drools Eclipse tooling here:

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/drools/org.drools.updatesite/5.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org.drools.updatesite-5.4.0-20120312.161534-443-assembly.zip

So, when using the jbpm-installer, you could update the URL of the Eclipse tooling in the build.properties to point to this file.  Or you could unzip this file on your local disk and then install the plugins from that local update site.

That should show the new menu items.

Kris

Answer (score 1):

Which version did you install? Kris usually use the latest snapshots. You can get them from https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/view/Drools%20jBPM/job/jbpm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/jbpm-distribution/target/

Cheers